# Prerequisites Skills to learn WordPress

Tags: theme-development

I'm new to WordPress and I was going through skills sets on some of the projects that are to be built in WordPress. The prerequisties that were mentioned are listed as below:

- HTML (obvious)
- CSS (that too is obvious!!!)
- PHP - Is this required to learn WordPress?

Moreover, Is there any other skill set that is required to learn WordPress (apart from WordPress...:-) )?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other skills include,

- Being a ninja.

But aside from that you pretty much summarized the core basics of what you need to familiarize yourself with to learn and develop with the WordPress platform.

- HTML
- CSS
- PHP
- jQuery/JavaScript

Are what make up the foundation of WordPress itself. How far you want to go with each of those is up to you, but don't be overwhelmed because despite there being some complexity involved with learning to develop, and develop well, that learning curve will eventually tip in your favor if you persist at honing your skills in the aforementioned.

The first place to start is with the WordPress Codex which can be found here http://codex.wordpress.org.

The Codex is the official documentation for the WordPress API system and much more, literally covering every aspect of the platform, development and its powerful list of functions. You will be referring to that a lot and you can learn just as much from the Codex by studying it and the example code provided within.

Fortunately there's no shortage of WordPress related resources around the Internet, without a doubt WordPress is the largest, most supported platform and a result tutorials, snippets and help concerning all things WordPress design and development are not in short supply.

I recommend sticking around this site too as its an invaluable resource for technical, code related questions for WordPress development and you'll no doubt make use of its vast wealth of knowledge contained within the question and answer threads.

There's many other resources I could recommend and hopefully some other people throw a few suggestions up too but in the meantime, if you haven't already, check out WP Tuts+ http://wp.tutsplus.com/ - which is one site that has a lot of great WP related content.

Nothing will beat getting your hands dirty by jumping into some theme building, even if just the basics like Pippin said.

Comment: Okies! I guess I can work as a designer-like with wordpress as I'm not sure about PHP!!!

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. Sorry mate, I sent my post before I finished writing. WordPress is PHP, while you don't need to know PHP to leverage the WordPress API to build sites, as a beneficial consequence, over time, you'll slowly learn, but you have to apply yourself a little. Good luck man.

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs..!!! It made my mind lot clearer!

Answer (score 1):

"learn WordPress" is a bit vague.... but if you mean develop for wordpress, then, yes, absolutely PHP is a needed skill.

javascript is another skill that is handy.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Apart from "Developing" for wordpress, is there anything WordPress can do,that doesn't require PHP as a needed skill?

Comment: You can do a lot of simple theme development with very little knowledge of PHP. Knowing and understanding PHP helps tremendously, but it is possible to build some very simple themes with minimal PHP knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @Pippin: I was under impression that with WordPress we can built websites w/o knowledge of any particular language (just with use of HTML,CSS, Javascript)

Comment: If your intent is to simply build a website, then you can totally do it with wordpress and not need any PHP skills.

Comment: I meant minimal because you need to at least understand how to implement many of the main template tags for showing post/page content, the loop, menus, etc.